# How to discard temporary created git branch

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging

Starting from a clean clone of http://github.com/maximveksler/IKnowKungFu

```
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(master) git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I wanted to create a temporary branch

```
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(master) git checkout -b submodule_nightmare
Switched to a new branch 'submodule_nightmare'
```

Made some changes

```
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(submodule_nightmare) ✗ git status
On branch submodule_nightmare
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   .gitmodules
    deleted:    Carthage/Checkouts/Nimble
    deleted:    Carthage/Checkouts/Quick

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   bin/setup
```

They I've decided to discard this whole branch (no commits have been made). How should I do this properly ?

I've tried to

```
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(submodule_nightmare) ✗ git checkout master
M   .gitignore
M   .gitmodules
D   Carthage/Checkouts/Nimble
D   Carthage/Checkouts/Quick
M   bin/setup
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(master) ✗ git branch -D submodule_nightmare
Deleted branch submodule_nightmare (was 42e46fd).
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(master) ✗ git branch
* master
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(master) ✗ git branch --list
* master
```

This seems to totally delete the branch, but when I tried to "recreate it from scratch" git seems to still remember the changes I've made:

```
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(master) ✗ git checkout -b submodule_nightmare
M   .gitignore
M   .gitmodules
D   Carthage/Checkouts/Nimble
D   Carthage/Checkouts/Quick
M   bin/setup
Switched to a new branch 'submodule_nightmare'
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(submodule_nightmare) ✗ git diff
➜  IKnowKungFu git:(submodule_nightmare) ✗ git status
On branch submodule_nightmare
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   .gitmodules
    deleted:    Carthage/Checkouts/Nimble
    deleted:    Carthage/Checkouts/Quick

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   bin/setup
```

Why like this?

*p.s. if you're wondering about the branch name, git / Carthage is giving me [hard times](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1146) lately..*

Comment: The `git status` command lists the commands you need in its output.  Try `git reset HEAD .` to unstage your changes for commit.  Then run `git checkout -- .` to discard the changes in your working directory.

Comment: @Cobster i don't have changes staged for commit. All did was change to a new branch, modify some files then (without committing) decide to dump that whole branch to "delete" it. This is the flow i've attempted and it didn't work. My question is if it's not a regular flow with git, and if not what is the best practice of creating a temporary branch and then deleting it ?

Comment: The output listed shows that you have the following 3 changes staged for commit: `.gitmodules`,`delete Carthage/Checkouts/Nimble`, and `delete Carthage/Checkouts/Quick`.  Additionally you have 2 changes in your working directory `.gitignore` and some files in `bin/setup`.  The commands in the previous comment will clean this up.   In my normal git workflow, I would have committed all these changes to the temporary branch, then deleted the branch, thus never pushing the changes to a remote repository.

Comment: @Cobster i'm sorry but by referring as "staging for commit" you mean files that are tracked by git and have been modified? If so YES, I did make some changes, and now looking for the best way to discard them.

Comment: Yes git has an additional concept of a "staging" area. These are modifications that will be included in the next commit. This is kind of like "Included Changes" if you are familar with TFS.  The branch itself you created does not maintain this state of your staged and/or working changes.  Thus when the branch is deleted, your changes are still exist.

Comment: @Cobster whoa never head of this before, could you please link to more info about this?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics

Answer (score 1):

The branch was deleted properly but the changes to the working directory were not touched. The changes made in the submodule_nightmare branch are not actually reverted/undone when you checkout back to master, nor when you recreate the submodule_nightmare branch again.

This happens because your two branches on are the same commit, and so there are no files to change in your working directory when you switch branches. This is a feature that allows you to, for example, make some changes on master, decide the work should be done on a different branch, and then change to that branch with `git checkout -b newcode` without having to in any way save your changes.

In order to revert all the changes made to a working directory's tracked files, a destructive command like `git reset --hard` needs to be run (which will undo your work, so be careful). Untracked files can be cleaned with some arguments to `git clean` (also destructive, use with caution).

If the two branches you're switching between are on different commits, and changes are made to a file that differs between both branches, an error will result if you try to switch branches without telling Git what to do. This is because Git avoids destroying your work unless you tell it to, so it aborts until you tell it how to handle the changed file.

As an example of that, let's say an updated Cartfile was committed to in master, but an existing branch, submodule_nightmare, does not have this commit. Then some changes were made to Cartfile in master but not committed. If you try to switch branches to submodule_nightmare using `git checkout submodule_nightmare`, the following error is seen:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    Cartfile
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Git clearly tells you that you need to save your changes in some way (commit or stash), or undo them (e.g. `git checkout master Cartfile` or manually edit), before it will allow you to switch.

Comment: Interesting and thank you for the insightful explanation. So If I understand you correctly, had I've committed my changes on submodule_nightmare and then proceeded to delete the branch it would work? My end goal is finding the effortless workflow for making some changes on the side, and then dropping the branch if I don't like the result.

Comment: It would have worked, yes, but the effortless workflow is more than likely the following three commands:
`git reset --hard`
`git checkout master`
`git branch -D submodule_nightmare`. The first gets rid of all changes, the second puts you back on master, the third deletes the branch. If there are remaining untracked files a `git clean -f` should get rid of anything that isn't in your .gitignore. Add a `-d` if you need to get rid of directories and `man git clean` can help for anything more tricky. Committing seems to be more work to me than just resetting.